# Automatic release with jboss [ example some ant scripts]

Tags: jboss

Currently I am doing the application release [app server jboss] manually by deploying the configuration files and ear. How can I automate it wit some ant script or ... ?

1 ) Not only copying to deploy directory I want to back up the file if it is getting replaced.
2) How ant to be use to deploy on a remote server?

Example :-

```
 <target name="copy" >

      <copy file="build_ol.xml" tofile="test_des/old.xml" overwrite="true" />

 </target>
```

Comment: Apparently you ended up with two accounts, which probably isn't very convenient. I believe you can request to have them merged by emailing the Stack Overflow team (there's a "contact us" link at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

You just need a script which will copy your application to JBOSS_HOME/server/{profile}/deploy directory. It will be automatically deployed,